# babel-import-plugin doesn't seem to reduce ant-design-vue size after use nuxt build config

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, antd, ant-design-vue

According to the doc  [Docs](https://www.antdv.com/docs/vue/introduce/)  It was recommended to use the modularized antd in order to ensure optimization and reduce the app size. However, I tried using the exact code in my nuxt build config but the app size remains the same before and after build using `yarn build`

Below is my nuxt build config and the screenshot to the before and after build

```
 build: {
    analyze: true, // Remove this mode before deployment
    babel: {
      plugins: [
        [
          "import",
          {
            libraryName: "ant-design-vue",
            libraryDirectory: "es",
            style: "css"
          },
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
```

Here is the build before and after adding the babel-import-plugin
[image]

Answer (score 0):

i just got this fixed and reduced the size drastically to this by only removing the ant-design plugin from the nuxt config.

Initially my plug look something like this

```
 plugins: [
    "@/plugins/antd-ui",
    { src: "@/plugins/vue-carousel", ssr: false }
    // "@/plugins/axios"
  ],
```

Then I removed the plugin to have something like this

```
 plugins: [
    { src: "@/plugins/vue-carousel", ssr: false }
    // "@/plugins/axios"
  ],
```

Now i have this minimal size [image]